# Cannot download files on WampServer

Tags: php, html, base64

I am trying to download files that I display dynamically in my PHP app. The file/s are stored as base64 in the database. On the frontend I am showing links for the files, however, when i click the link browser gives a network error

> Couldn't Download - Network Error.

here is the code block:

```
foreach ($custom_tasks as $single_custom_task) {
    if (strtolower($single_custom_task['task_week']) == strtolower('week4') 
        && strtolower($single_custom_task['student_group']) == strtolower($student_group)) 
    {
        echo '<div class="activity-container">';
        echo '<h5 id="custom-task" class="text-start">Title : ' . $single_custom_task['task_name'] . '</h5>';
        echo '<p>Description: ' . $single_custom_task['task_desc'] . '</p>';
        if (base64_decode($single_custom_task['file_data'], true)) {
            echo '<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,' . 
                    $single_custom_task['file_data'] . 
                    '" download="' . $single_custom_task['file_name'] . '">
                    <i class="fas fa-file"></i> ' . 
                        $single_custom_task['file_name'] . '</a>';
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid file data';
        }
            
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

I tried changing the download limit in the `php.ini` file, using different browsers and checked if `.htaccess` file was interfering.

Comment: @RiggsFolly not sure what would be wrong with that? They specified the file name the client should suggest, as far as I can tell, and that should be fine.

Comment: Does this happen for any attempt to download a file?

Comment: This [post on microsoft answers may help](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/couldnt-download-network-issue/c1b73bd5-e490-425b-8420-e4e86269d7fb)

Comment: yes i tried different files, different sizes. On chrome is says check internet connection. The file data itself is correct because i viewed the file in an iframe and it works.

Comment: while you put the whole file data in your markup, i suspect that this is not an download limit issue because all data has been already sended to you when you see the base64 string in your markup. I suspect a browser setting or issue if this does not work. Maybe you should post your resulting markup instead of the server side php code.

Comment: I went through all browser settings for downloads. Tried on a different laptop as well.